# How to get and pass the trigger captured text to a script function invocation in iTerm2?

Tags: python, iterm2

I was trying to add a trigger to capture text in some pattern and pass it to a Python script

My script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    @iterm2.RPC
    async def myfunc(captured_text):
        print(captured_text)

    await myfunc.async_register(connection)

iterm2.run_forever(main)
```

I tried to set the trigger Parameters with `myfunc(captured_text: trigger.captured_strings)` in the profile trigger settings, it didn't work and the error `Reference to undefined variable "trigger.captured_strings"` was reported.

Comment: Check this example: https://gist.github.com/ddbeck/1421861